# Listar em PHP usando Next e Previous

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Tenho um sistema de `next` e `previous` com `zoom`
O que eu quero é que quando eu clicar no `next`  ou `previous` produto mude por **ID**  vinda do Banco.
e no zoom apresente o zoom da imagem que esteja na página.
pois estou enfrentando problemas.

[image: Nesse Modelo]

Estou usando para apresentar assim:

```html
<!-- /Grid-->
<section class="slider">
<div class="slide slide--current" data-content="content-<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>">
<div class="slide__mover">
<div class="zoomer flex-center">
<img class="zoomer__image" src="foto/<?php  echo $rows_cursos['arquivo'] ?>" alt=""  style="width:80%;height:80%;"/>
<div class="preview">
<img src="" alt="" />
<div class="zoomer__area zoomer__area--size-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<h2 class="slide__title"><span><?php  echo $rows_cursos['prod_nome'] ?></span><?php  echo $rows_cursos['prod_fabricante'] ?></h2>
</div> 
</section>

<!-- /Menus-->
<nav class="slider__nav">
<button class="button button--nav-prev"><i class="icon icon--arrow-left"></i><span class="text-hidden">Previous product</span></button>
<button class="button button--zoom"><i class="icon icon--zoom"></i><span class="text-hidden">View details</span></button>
<button class="button button--nav-next"><i class="icon icon--arrow-right"></i><span class="text-hidden">Next product</span></button>
</nav>
  
<!-- /slider-->
<section class="content">
<div class="content__item" id="content-<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>">
<img class="content__item-img rounded-right" src="foto/<?php  echo $rows_cursos['arquivo'] ?>" alt="Apple Watch Content" />
<div class="content__item-inner">
<h2><?php  echo $rows_cursos['prod_nome'] ?></h2>
<h3><?php  echo $rows_cursos['prod_fabricante'] ?></h3>
<p><?php  echo $rows_cursos['prod_desc'] ?></p>
<h3><a href="#"> <?php  echo $rows_cursos['prod_preco'] ?></a></h3>
</div>
</div>
<button class="button button--close"><i class="icon icon--circle-cross"></i><span class="text-hidden">Close</span></button>
</section>
```

Comment: "pois estou enfrentando problemas".... Qual problema?

Comment: nesse list ele está me retornando apenas o primeiro produto do banco no next e prev ele não passa aos outros produtos do banco. mas se eu dou zoom ele sobrescreve o produto com o segundo produto do banco.  como nesse teste : http://imperionutry.esy.es/aula/index_prod_acao.php